# Using map function in Pyspark for filtering

Tags: pyspark, bigdata, rdd

I want to compare two tables. Table A consists of 2cr records and around 5p columns but needs to use only tran_name and table B consists of around 5k records and a single column.
Requirements are as follows:

1. If consider table B has a value as ABC in row 1 so now I have to filter all the records like ABC FROM TABLE A and this needs to be done for all the rows present in table B.
2. I tried using for loop in Pyspark for the same purpose but the time is taken and memory occupied was huge.
3. Now I plan to use map, lambda function
   My code is as follows

   ```
   def matches(A,i):    
        Rdd2=A.filter(A(col('tran_name'))).rlike(i)
        return rdd2


    matches_udf=udf(matches,StringType())
    df=B.rdd.map(lambda x: x.matches_udf(A,x)).collect()
   ```

But it is showing an error

Comment: are you trying to filter dataframes? see [`filter()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html)

Comment: No trying to filter records from dataframe

Comment: It would be clearer if you provided a sample input dataframe and desired output dataframe. Reading the description doesn't really make it clear.